# Changing values in XML string in PHP

Tags: php, xml

I have this XML string.In which i had concatinate some variables in it.i just want to clarify that when these variable change,does values in XML string also change or not?

```
    <?php
$nvpstr="
    <Source>
        <Company>".$company."</Company>
        <LeadId>".$leadid."</LeadId>
        <IpAddress>".$IP."</IpAddress>
</Source>";
?>
```

and is it a true XML to be sent via POST considering that format they provided is this.

Comment: Before or after... What is the context in which we are capturing the value? Pass by reference vs. pass by value would give you two completely different outcomes. What is a complete, beginning-to-end script?

Comment: Is it that difficult to change the parameters and then `echo` the XML ?

Answer (score 1):

if you change those variables AFTER that block they wont.

or in simple:

```
$a = 'foo';
$b = 'my $a is: '.$a;
$a = 'bar';
```

wont change `$b` to `'bar'` and an `echo $b;` will print out `my $a is: foo`